# ngFor com checkbox está selecionando todos os valores

Tags: html, angular, loop

Tenho o seguinte checkbox com uma estrutura de repetição:

```
      <div *ngFor="let tela of telas" class="custom-control custom-checkbox check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{tela.nome_tela}}" [(ngModel)]="operador.permissao_telas" name="{{tela.id}}" class="custom-control-input" checked>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{tela.nome_tela}}">{{tela.nome_tela}}</label>
      </div>
```

Este é meu modelo:

```
export class Operador{
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    permissao_telas: number[];
}
```

No meu componente eu faço:

```
 operador:Operador = new Operador();
```

O problema é que quando clico em algum check, todos os outros check são selecionados também.

Já tentei fazer com index e também não deu certo.

Comment: Coloque dentro da div do `ngFor` um `<p>{{tela | json}}</p>` e verifique se os dados aparecem como o eperado

Answer (score 0):

Remova o checked no final do seu input no html